# How to encrypt admin password?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

In my java web app, admin account will create user account, where the password will be encrypted, using `StandardPasswordEncoder` class, that's easy. But how to encrypt the admin password, which i already stored in `MySQL` database?

Comment: why you don't edit your admin password with the encrypted password ?

Comment: u mean edit in mysql directly? but the password encoder in my java controller class..

Comment: what algorithm you are using MD5 AES or what in your java controller?

Comment: The encryption you are talking about is something like a custom encryption algorithm or a standard one like md5 for which @YCF_L has already answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to encrypt the admin password, which i already stored in mysql
>   database?

You can edit your password :

```
UPDATE table_name SET pass = MD5(pass);
-- --------------------------^^^-------
-- This can be any Standard encryption algorithm, you can check the link above
```

You can take a look about [Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

> how if i only want to encrypt only the admin password? the other users
>   password will be encrypted by admin in java controller class.

You can mark your password like a master admin for example you can add a column in your table that make difference between the admin and the ordinary users, consider you have a big enterprise in this case one admin account is not enough, you need many admin accounts, and in base of this column you can encrypt the admin account with an algorithm and the others with another algorithm.

---

## Encrypt password using SHA-256

> I managed to encrypt the admin password, but i can't log in to my web
>   app coz the StandardPasswordEncoder class in the web app is using
>   SHA-256 hashing algorithm

**SHA-256 != MD5**, this is clear so you have to use the same algothm in the both side code and database, in your case you are using `SHA-256` i assume you are using a function like this :

**CODE**

```
public static String sha256(String base) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(base.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

This will encrypt admin like this :

```
admin = 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
```

**DATABASE**

So in your database you have to encrypt your password like this :

```
SELECT SHA2('admin', 256);
```

The update query should look like this :

```
UPDATE table_name SET pass = SHA2(pass, 256) WHERE admin_master = true;
-- -------------Field to check if it is admin or not ---^
```

So when you try to log in you have to check if it is admin or not, if admin encrypt your password with SHA-256 and check if the user exist or not, else if the user is ordanary user, check with your previouse algorithm.

Hope this can give you an idea.

Comment: how if i only want to encrypt only the admin password? the other users password will be encrypted by admin in java controller class..

Comment: If you have a column where you specify the user privilege as admin you can do
       UPDATE table_name SET pass = MD5(pass) WHERE previlage="admin";

Comment: @Shahril you can mark your password like a master admin for example you can add a column in your table that make difference between the admin and the ordinary users, consider you have a big enterprise in this case one admin account is not enough, you need many admin acoounts, and in base of this column you can encrypt the admin account with an algorithm and the others with another algorithm, you get the idea

Comment: arrghh...i managed to encrypt the admin password, but i can't log in to my web app coz the StandardPasswordEncoder class in the web app is using SHA-256 hashing algorithm. any idea @YCF_L ?

Comment: @Shahril what algorithm you are using in your database MD5 ?

Comment: @Shahril no you should not use MD5 ok i will edit my answer just wait

Comment: thanks a million bro. I'll try it and let u know how it goes...:)

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: thank you @zaph i think this is a big topic, thank you for the advice hope the OP understand this, my answer was like that because he already said **coz the StandardPasswordEncoder class in the web app is using SHA-256 hashing algorithm**

Comment: I understand your answer. But what is at stake is the users of the system, against that how does one justify insecure solutions.